# Is it possible to specify the schema when connecting to postgres with JDBC?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc, database-schema

Is it possible? Can i specify it on the connection URL? How to do that?

Answer (score 326, accepted):

I know this was answered already, but I just ran into the same issue trying to specify the schema to use for the liquibase command line.

**Update**
As of JDBC v[9.4](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html#connection-parameters) you can specify the url with the new currentSchema parameter like so:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema
```

Appears based on an earlier patch:

http://web.archive.org/web/20141025044151/http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Patch-to-allow-setting-schema-search-path-in-the-connectionURL-td2174512.html

Which proposed url's like so:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?searchpath=myschema
```

Comment: Yes but at the moment of the writing (late 2012) it's not a part of the [9.1 driver](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/), see: [Connection Parameters](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/connect.html#connection-parameters).

Comment: Did you try it? Because it wasn't listed as part of the previous driver but it still worked.

Comment: Tried with 9.3-1101-jdbc41 and 9.1, doesn't work for me

Comment: @IgnacioA.Poletti Try using the JDCB `setSchema` method after creating your connection. Works for me with a recent postgres driver.

Comment: searchpath didn't work.... using 9.4. see: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html#connection-parameters

Comment: It looks like they added a new currentSchema according to that link.

Comment: Neither of these work for me.  When I prepend "schema." to my table names, it DOES work, so it should indeed be a problem of just not being in the right schema, but neither of the above options themselves appear to set the schema.  PostgreSQL 9.5

Comment: We solved this problem by also using a different (newer) JDBC driver. In our case `postgresql-9.4.1209.jdbc42.jar` worked together with a `9.5` database and the `?currentSchema=myschema` syntax.

Comment: It worked for me for JDBC version 9.4-1206, Thanks for the info

Answer (score 89):

As of version 9.4, you can use the `currentSchema` [parameter](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connection-parameters) in your connection string.

For example:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema
```

Answer (score 55):

If it is possible in your environment, you could also set the user's default schema to your desired schema:

```
ALTER USER user_name SET search_path to 'schema'
```

Comment: Probably better to ALTER the database itself so that the same user can connect to different databases with different search_paths if need be:

ALTER DATABASE dbname SET search_path TO public,schemaname;

Answer (score 47):

I don't believe there is a way to specify the schema in the connection string.  It appears you have to execute

```
set search_path to 'schema'
```

after the connection is made to specify the schema.

Comment: This worked for me, specifically using the "Connection" instance to run:

`Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

try {
    statement.execute("set search_path to '" + schema + "'");
} finally {
    statement.close();
}`

Comment: There is a way to specify the default schema in the connection string (jdbc uri). See answers below.

Answer (score 10):

## `DataSource` – `setCurrentSchema`

When instantiating a [`DataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) implementation, look for a method to set the current/default schema.

For example, on the [`PGSimpleDataSource`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html) class call [`setCurrentSchema`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.html#setCurrentSchema-java.lang.String-).

```
org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource ( );
dataSource.setServerName ( "localhost" );
dataSource.setDatabaseName ( "your_db_here_" );
dataSource.setPortNumber ( 5432 );
dataSource.setUser ( "postgres" );
dataSource.setPassword ( "your_password_here" );
dataSource.setCurrentSchema ( "your_schema_name_here_" );  // <----------
```

If you leave the schema unspecified, Postgres defaults to a schema named `public` within the database. See the manual, section 5.9.2 [*The Public Schema*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PUBLIC). To quote hat manual:

> In the previous sections we created tables without specifying any schema names. By default such tables (and other objects) are automatically put into a schema named “public”. Every new database contains such a schema.

Comment: "*attempts to connect to a schema*" - That's a bit misleading. The driver does not connect "to a schema", but to a _database_. Which schema is used by queries depends on the current setting of the [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH)

Answer (score 8):

In Go with "sql.DB" (note the `search_path` with underscore):

```
postgres://user:password@host/dbname?sslmode=disable&search_path=schema
```

Answer (score 7):

I submitted an updated version of a patch to the PostgreSQL JDBC driver to enable this a few years back.  You'll have to build the PostreSQL JDBC driver from source (after adding in the patch) to use it:

http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2008-07/msg00012.php

http://jdbc.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget [`SET SCHEMA 'myschema'`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-set.html) which you could use in a separate Statement

> SET SCHEMA 'value' is an alias for SET search_path TO value. Only one
>   schema can be specified using this syntax.

And since 9.4 and possibly earlier versions on the JDBC driver, there is support for the [`setSchema(String schemaName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setSchema(java.lang.String)) method.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried: currentSchema, searchpath, search_path in the key-value section and nothing works for me.
I have found work around with the "options" key word:

`postgresql://host:port/dbname?options=-c%20search_path%3Dschema_name`

Comment: asyncpg doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Updated on 2024

If you want to set schema, use `?options=-c%20search_path=`

Full url

```sql
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?options=-c%20search_path=test,public,pg_catalog
```

According to the postgresql JDBC doc
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/