# Database sharding and JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa, sharding

I am working on a Java application that requires [horizontal partitioning of data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29) in different PostgreSQL servers. I would like to use a JPA framework and Spring for transaction management.

The most popular frameworks for sharding data with JPA seem to be [Hibernate Shards](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/shards.html), which appears to be no longer in development, and [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/) [Slice](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-openjpa/index.html), which does not support virtual shards (one of my requirements). Are there any other options that I'm missing, or a way to get around the OpenJPA limitation?

Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Can detail "virtual shards", please?

Comment: Hi Aubin. Basically a virtual (or logical) shard is a shard that does not reside in a separate server, but on the same server with some kind of boundary, say in a separate schema.

Comment: Wouldn't Hibernate's multi-tenancy with partitioning support your use case?

Comment: @dinukadev - I just came across Hibernate multi-tenancy and I am investigating it. Another possible solution is to use OpenJPA Slice and have a different user per schema with different default search path.

Comment: How do you know it does not support virtual shards ? It looks like  each slice is defined by a jdbc connection property that could point to the same machine.

Comment: Same machine yes, same database no since there is no way in the PostgreSQL JDBC connection string to supply the schema. That being said, [someone did a patch for it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5491562/1870723).

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at [Sharding-JDBC](https://github.com/dangdangdotcom/sharding-jdbc), it is a JDBC driver for shard databases and tables, can adapter for any ORM frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into EclipseLink?  It supports JPA2 and horizontal sharding.

The [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Partitioning) says it supports Sharding over multiple database instance