# Using postgreSQL schema with iBatis

Tags: java, jdbc, ibatis

I'm facing an issue with iBatis and PostgreSQL schemas. 
When I use the public schema i don't face any issue. Everything worked fine for me.

My URL connection string was like the below:

```
jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5678/dbname
```

But when i tried to use the same database using a different schema i always get

```
com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in SqlMapProcessedFiles.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the getProcessedFiles-InlineParameterMap.  
--- Check the statement (query failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ERROR: relation "table name" does not exist
```

My url connection string looks like the below:

```
jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5678/dbname?searchpath=schemaName
```

I'm using ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar with postgresql-8.0-325.jdbc2.jar.

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Comment: Pg JDBC driver doesn't allow you to specify search path, you have to connect first then set it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc

Answer (score 1):

Define your connection properties as following:

- Connection URL : `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres` and make the
- Configure the `search_path` in the `postgres` database properties and define the search_path variables as show.

[image: Sample View]