# Get my dropwizard application operating against a specified schema

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, dropwizard

How do I get my dropwizard application to operate against a specified schema, a schema other than the default 'public'?
The postgres user has all privileges on schemas 'public' and 'schema1'. It should be doing a lookups on 'schema1' tables but it comes back as (tablename) doesnt exist, even though it clearly does. This is because its looking at the 'public' schema

Should this be handled on the application side i.e dropwizard hibernate config, or on the database side. How should i tackle this? Is there a standard way?

Thanks guys

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/ The third answer will be useful I think. There seems to be a limitation from PostgreSQL for the schema handling in the JDBC URLs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to specify schema when connecting to postgres with JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc)

Answer (score 0):

The dropwizard use a yml configuration file, in this file you can configure your database connection, the correctly use is the configuration file.