# Use another schema than public in geoserver monitoring plugin

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, database-schema, geoserver

We want to use the [Geoserver Monitoring Plugin](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/monitoring/index.html), based on a PostgreSQL 9.3 database.

It works fine except that the plugin create the tables `request` and `request_resources` in the `public` schema, while we want them to be separated in a schema called `monitoring`.

What we tried:

- Add the searchpath to the jdbc url in the file monitoring/db.properties (See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820666/291541)

  `url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?searchpath=monitoring`
- Add a line in the hibernate.properties file to force the schema:

  `hibernate.default_schema=monitoring`
- Create a user dedicated to that role and set his default schema to monitoring (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4168794/291541)

  `set search_path to 'monitoring'`

Unfortunately nothing worked. The tables are not created in the monitoring schema. An error appeared in geoserver.log with that last solution:

> ERROR [util.JDBCExceptionReporter] - ERROR: relation
>   "hibernate_sequence" does not exist

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the monitoring plugin so i can only give you a clue about your problem.

Your first solution will not work because geoserver uses and [old jdbc driver](http://sourceforge.net/p/geoserver/mailman/message/33606927/), but probably you can update it yourself savely. Just delete the old and put the new in web-inf/lib