# Spring Boot Actuator Liquibase endpoint fail

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, spring-boot-actuator

I'm trying to use Liquibase with Spring Boot.
Here is my `application.properties` file:

```
# ----------------------------------------
# DATA PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxx:5432/dev
spring.datasource.schema=my_schema
spring.datasource.username=my_username
spring.datasource.password=my_password

# LIQUIBASE (LiquibaseProperties)
liquibase.default-schema=${spring.datasource.schema}
liquibase.user=${spring.datasource.username}
liquibase.password=${spring.datasource.password}
```

Change sets are well applied (table creation is ok).

The problem comes when I access `/liquibase` actuator's endpoint, I get a 500 error:

> Unable to get Liquibase changelog

I also get the following log:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.databasechangelog" does not exist

If thing the problem is the schema prefix used to access changelog table: "public" versus "my_schema".

I thought `spring.datasource.schema` was the right parameter to set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution ([come from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc#4820666)):

```
# ----------------------------------------
# DATA PROPERTIES
# ----------------------------------------

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xxxxxx:5432/dev?currentSchema=my_schema
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here - I think that the issue is that your 'real' schema is being set by the `spring.datasource.schema` but the liquibase tables are being stored in `public` and it may be that the Spring Boot actuator doesn't know that those can be separate.

Comment: Unfortunately no, tables are rightly stored in "my_schema".