# PhpStorm - ERROR: type "hstore" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, phpstorm

I use primary pgAdmin to browse and edit my PostgreSQL database. Now I would like to use PhpStorm.

In PhpStorm I can browse my tables, but I can not edit data. When I try I get error:

> [42704] ERROR: type "hstore" does not exist
>
> Kde: compilation of PL/pgSQL function "on_update" near line 3

Function *on_update* is on update trigger and it save old row to history table and it uses hstore type.

PhpStorm uses *postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar* driver. I don't know if it is driver error or PhpStorm error. I know that in pgAdmin it works and in PhpStorm not.

Comment: You need to run `create extension hstore` as the Postgres superuser:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html

Comment: I've heard this advice already. Is it realy this case? I mean.. It works in pgAdmin so the extension has to be created already or not?

Comment: The error message is clear: the extension is **not** installed and the function `on_update` is using `hstore`. I guess pgAdmin doesn't use that function (wherever that function comes from)

Comment: Ok. I will try. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: I am afraid it did not work. I checked our build process and it contains `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore;` so the extension is installed.

Comment: The error message clearly contradicts your last comment. You might have installed that extension in a different database. Or it's installed in a separate schema and that schema is not in the search_path of the user you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work with same environment as Vojtěch and I have found that the extension is indeed created and present. But in different schema (public) then the current connection operates (the PostgreSQL `search_path`). There is probably bug in PhpStorm as its not respecting PostgreSQL user's default search_path.

Some workarounds (for DB console only):

- In database console you use `RESET SEARCH_PATH;` statement.
- You can enforce `search_path` on JDBC connection, see the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc).