# Tables are not created in the specified schema

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to integrate spring boot with postgres db. 
Everything works fine except that the tables are being created in the public schema even though I am specifying a particular schema in the application.properties

```
spring.datasource.schema=AngSpring
```

### application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/NGP_DB
spring.datasource.schema=AngSpring
spring.datasource.username=jdbcusr
spring.datasource.password=password
```

You can see in the postgres db screenshot that the **task_list** table is created under 'public' schema. According to the property file it should come under the 'AngSpring' schema.

[image: Schema description]

Please correct me if Iam doing anything wrong in the code.

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

Answer (score 3):

I guess the `spring.datasource.schema` property is used to specify the location of a [concrete schema script file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) in your application to generate the database, so you should remove it.

Instead, it seems that you want to use the one that Hibernate guesses from your entitities and put it in an specific schema location in your postgres database. Use the schema in the url instead:

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/NGP_DB?currentSchema=AngSpring
```

**See also:**

- [Is it possible to specify schema when connecting to postgres with JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc)