# how to properly specify database schema in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

in my spring boot / hibernate application, I need to connect to a Postgres database "ax2012_1", which belong to the "dbo" schema.

I have the following application.properties:

```
# Database
db.driver: org.postgresql.Driver
db.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ax2012_1
db.username: my_user_name
db.password: my_password

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ax2012_1
spring.datasource.username=my_user_name
spring.datasource.password=my_password
spring.datasource.schema=dbo 

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
entitymanager.packagesToScan: com.mycompany.myproduct.data
```

my DatabaseConfig.java looks like this:

```
package com.uptake.symphony.data.configs;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfig {

  // ------------------------
  // PUBLIC METHODS
  // ------------------------

  /**
   * DataSource definition for database connection. Settings are read from
   * the application.properties file (using the env object).
   */
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("db.driver"));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("db.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("db.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("db.password"));
    return dataSource;
  }

  /**
   * Declare the JPA entity manager factory.
   */
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory =
        new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

    // Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
        env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

    // Vendor adapter
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    // Hibernate properties
    Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.dialect", 
        env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.show_sql", 
        env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", 
        env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);
    additionalProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "dbo");

    return entityManagerFactory;
  }

  /**
   * Declare the transaction manager.
   */
  @Bean
  public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
        entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
  }

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Autowired
  private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;
}
```

From the startup log, I can tell, that hibernate is, in fact, discovering my table "custtable":

```
Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
2016-09-10 15:27:15.866  INFO 69384 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-09-10 15:27:15.867  INFO 69384 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-09-10 15:27:16.096  INFO 69384 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-09-10 15:27:18.367  INFO 69384 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2016-09-10 15:27:18.378  INFO 69384 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder    : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-09-10 15:27:18.499  WARN 69384 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): com.myconpany.myproduct.data.CusttableCompositeKey
2016-09-10 15:27:18.499  WARN 69384 --- [           main] org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass          : HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): com.myconpany.myproduct.data.CusttableCompositeKey
2016-09-10 15:27:18.508  INFO 69384 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-09-10 15:27:18.932  INFO 69384 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-09-10 15:27:18.933  INFO 69384 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-09-10 15:27:18.943  INFO 69384 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-09-10 15:27:18.993  INFO 69384 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: dbo.custtable
2016-09-10 15:27:18.993  INFO 69384 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [custexcludecollectionfee, interestcode_br, servicecodeondlvaddress_br, stateinscription_mx, insscei_br, memo, inventprofiletype_ru, rfidcasetagging, irs1099cindicator, agencylocationcode, enterprisecode, issueownentrycertificate_w, invoicepostingtype_ru, affiliated_ru, contactpersonid, creditcardaddressverification, taxgstreliefgroupheading_my, rfidpallettagging, ccmnum_br, custfinaluser_br, orderentrydeadlinegroupid, accountnum, subsegmentid, entrycertificaterequired_w, salesgroup, bankcentralbankpurposetext, suppitemgroupid, curp_mx, pdscustrebategroupid, commercialregisterinsetnumber, mandatoryvatdate_pl, usecashdisc, inventsiteid, custitemgroupid, defaultdirectdebitmandate, taxwithholdcalculate_th, mcrmergedroot, exportsales_pl, cashdisc, syncversion, federalcomments, girotypeprojinvoice, syncentityid, intercompanyautocreateorders, icmscontributor_br, finecode_br, del_modifiedtime, rfiditemtagging, companynafcode, ienum_br, dataareaid, inventlocation, consday_jp, unitedvatinvoice_lt, foreignerid_br, partition, blocked, vatnum, markupgroup, incltax, custwhtcontributiontype_br, salesdistrictid, girotypefreetextinvoice, currency, maincontactworker, taxgroup, authorityoffice_it, pdsrebatetmagroup, salespoolid, intercompanydirectdelivery, presencetype_br, paymentreference_ee, mcrmergedparent, linedisc, partycountry, commercialregister, multilinedisc, isresident_lv, numbersequencegroup, rfc_mx, paymspec, suframapiscofins_br, fednonfedindicator, invoiceaddress, ouraccountnum, shipcarrierfuelsurcharge, segmentid, defaultdimension, vendaccount, dlvmode, identificationnumber, suframa_br, fiscalcode, taxlicensenum, shipcarrieraccount, destinationcodeid, einvoice, nit_br, cnae_br, paymmode, paymsched, companychainid, girotypeinterestnote, cashdiscbasedays, freightzone, birthcountycode_it, daxintegrationid, packmaterialfeelicensenum, girotypeaccountstatement, defaultinventstatusid, pdsfreightaccrued, shipcarrierid, modifieddatetime, custtradingpartnercode, lvpaymtranscodes, birthplace_it, clearingperiod, enterprisenumber, mandatorycreditlimit, companytype_mx, salescalendarid, einvoiceeannum, websalesorderdisplay, custgroup, dlvreason, factoringaccount, orgid, commercialregistersection, creditcardaddressverificationvoid, paymidtype, dlvterm, residenceforeigncountryregionid_it, paymtermid, statisticsgroup, packagedepositexcempt_pl, forecastdmpinclude, companyidsiret, modifiedby, girotype, birthdate_it, createddatetime, party, taxwithholdgroup_th, shipcarrierblindshipment, onetimecustomer, accountstatement, del_createdtime, lineofbusinessid, taxbordernumber_fi, partystate, expressbilloflading, bankaccount, regnum_w, enddisc, commissiongroup, intercompanyallowindirectcreation, paymdayid, passportno_hu, creditrating, custclassificationid, generateincomingfiscaldocument_br, pbacustgroupid, shipcarrieraccountcode, recid, einvoiceregister_it, intbank_lv, bankcentralbankpurposecode, taxwithholdcalculate_in, usepurchrequest, fiscaldoctype_pl, girotypecollectionletter, pricegroup, invoiceaccount, creditcardaddressverificationlevel, recversion, foreignresident_ru, creditcardcvc, bankcustpaymidtable, cnpjcpfnum_br, inventprofileid_ru, taxperiodpaymentcode_pl, custexcludeinterestcharges, issuercountry_hu, creditmax, suframanumber_br]
2016-09-10 15:27:18.994  INFO 69384 --- [           main] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
```

However, when I run "findById" from my DAO:

```
public Custtable getById(Class<Custtable> class1, CusttableCompositeKey custtableCompositeKey) {
        Custtable ct = entityManager.find(Custtable.class, custtableCompositeKey);
        LOG.debug("customer.ct.accountNum:  " + ct.getAccountnum());
        return entityManager.find(Custtable.class, custtableCompositeKey);
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Hibernate: select custtable0_.accountnum as accountn1_0_0_, custtable0_.dataareaid as dataarea2_0_0_, custtable0_.partition as partitio3_0_0_, custtable0_.accountstatement as accounts4_0_0_, custtable0_.affiliated_ru as affiliat5_0_0_, custtable0_.agencylocationcode as agencylo6_0_0_, custtable0_.authorityoffice_it as authorit7_0_0_, custtable0_.bankaccount as bankacco8_0_0_, custtable0_.bankcentralbankpurposecode as bankcent9_0_0_, custtable0_.bankcentralbankpurposetext as bankcen10_0_0_, custtable0_.bankcustpaymidtable as bankcus11_0_0_, custtable0_.birthcountycode_it as birthco12_0_0_, custtable0_.birthdate_it as birthda13_0_0_, custtable0_.birthplace_it as birthpl14_0_0_, custtable0_.blocked as blocked15_0_0_, custtable0_.cashdisc as cashdis16_0_0_, custtable0_.cashdiscbasedays as cashdis17_0_0_, custtable0_.ccmnum_br as ccmnum_18_0_0_, custtable0_.clearingperiod as clearin19_0_0_, custtable0_.cnae_br as cnae_br20_0_0_, custtable0_.cnpjcpfnum_br as cnpjcpf21_0_0_, custtable0_.commercialregister as commerc22_0_0_, custtable0_.commercialregisterinsetnumber as commerc23_0_0_, custtable0_.commercialregistersection as commerc24_0_0_, custtable0_.commissiongroup as commiss25_0_0_, custtable0_.companychainid as company26_0_0_, custtable0_.companyidsiret as company27_0_0_, custtable0_.companynafcode as company28_0_0_, custtable0_.companytype_mx as company29_0_0_, custtable0_.consday_jp as consday30_0_0_, custtable0_.contactpersonid as contact31_0_0_, custtable0_.createddatetime as created32_0_0_, custtable0_.creditcardaddressverification as creditc33_0_0_, custtable0_.creditcardaddressverificationlevel as creditc34_0_0_, custtable0_.creditcardaddressverificationvoid as creditc35_0_0_, custtable0_.creditcardcvc as creditc36_0_0_, custtable0_.creditmax as creditm37_0_0_, custtable0_.creditrating as creditr38_0_0_, custtable0_.curp_mx as curp_mx39_0_0_, custtable0_.currency as currenc40_0_0_, custtable0_.custclassificationid as custcla41_0_0_, custtable0_.custexcludecollectionfee as custexc42_0_0_, custtable0_.custexcludeinterestcharges as custexc43_0_0_, custtable0_.custfinaluser_br as custfin44_0_0_, custtable0_.custgroup as custgro45_0_0_, custtable0_.custitemgroupid as custite46_0_0_, custtable0_.custtradingpartnercode as custtra47_0_0_, custtable0_.custwhtcontributiontype_br as custwht48_0_0_, custtable0_.daxintegrationid as daxinte49_0_0_, custtable0_.defaultdimension as default50_0_0_, custtable0_.defaultdirectdebitmandate as default51_0_0_, custtable0_.defaultinventstatusid as default52_0_0_, custtable0_.del_createdtime as del_cre53_0_0_, custtable0_.del_modifiedtime as del_mod54_0_0_, custtable0_.destinationcodeid as destina55_0_0_, custtable0_.dlvmode as dlvmode56_0_0_, custtable0_.dlvreason as dlvreas57_0_0_, custtable0_.dlvterm as dlvterm58_0_0_, custtable0_.einvoice as einvoic59_0_0_, custtable0_.einvoiceeannum as einvoic60_0_0_, custtable0_.einvoiceregister_it as einvoic61_0_0_, custtable0_.enddisc as enddisc62_0_0_, custtable0_.enterprisecode as enterpr63_0_0_, custtable0_.enterprisenumber as enterpr64_0_0_, custtable0_.entrycertificaterequired_w as entryce65_0_0_, custtable0_.exportsales_pl as exports66_0_0_, custtable0_.expressbilloflading as express67_0_0_, custtable0_.factoringaccount as factori68_0_0_, custtable0_.federalcomments as federal69_0_0_, custtable0_.fednonfedindicator as fednonf70_0_0_, custtable0_.finecode_br as finecod71_0_0_, custtable0_.fiscalcode as fiscalc72_0_0_, custtable0_.fiscaldoctype_pl as fiscald73_0_0_, custtable0_.forecastdmpinclude as forecas74_0_0_, custtable0_.foreignerid_br as foreign75_0_0_, custtable0_.foreignresident_ru as foreign76_0_0_, custtable0_.freightzone as freight77_0_0_, custtable0_.generateincomingfiscaldocument_br as generat78_0_0_, custtable0_.girotype as girotyp79_0_0_, custtable0_.girotypeaccountstatement as girotyp80_0_0_, custtable0_.girotypecollectionletter as girotyp81_0_0_, custtable0_.girotypefreetextinvoice as girotyp82_0_0_, custtable0_.girotypeinterestnote as girotyp83_0_0_, custtable0_.girotypeprojinvoice as girotyp84_0_0_, custtable0_.icmscontributor_br as icmscon85_0_0_, custtable0_.identificationnumber as identif86_0_0_, custtable0_.ienum_br as ienum_b87_0_0_, custtable0_.incltax as incltax88_0_0_, custtable0_.insscei_br as insscei89_0_0_, custtable0_.intbank_lv as intbank90_0_0_, custtable0_.intercompanyallowindirectcreation as interco91_0_0_, custtable0_.intercompanyautocreateorders as interco92_0_0_, custtable0_.intercompanydirectdelivery as interco93_0_0_, custtable0_.interestcode_br as interes94_0_0_, custtable0_.inventlocation as inventl95_0_0_, custtable0_.inventprofileid_ru as inventp96_0_0_, custtable0_.inventprofiletype_ru as inventp97_0_0_, custtable0_.inventsiteid as invents98_0_0_, custtable0_.invoiceaccount as invoice99_0_0_, custtable0_.invoiceaddress as invoic100_0_0_, custtable0_.invoicepostingtype_ru as invoic101_0_0_, custtable0_.irs1099cindicator as irs102_0_0_, custtable0_.isresident_lv as isresi103_0_0_, custtable0_.issueownentrycertificate_w as issueo104_0_0_, custtable0_.issuercountry_hu as issuer105_0_0_, custtable0_.linedisc as linedi106_0_0_, custtable0_.lineofbusinessid as lineof107_0_0_, custtable0_.lvpaymtranscodes as lvpaym108_0_0_, custtable0_.maincontactworker as mainco109_0_0_, custtable0_.mandatorycreditlimit as mandat110_0_0_, custtable0_.mandatoryvatdate_pl as mandat111_0_0_, custtable0_.markupgroup as markup112_0_0_, custtable0_.mcrmergedparent as mcrmer113_0_0_, custtable0_.mcrmergedroot as mcrmer114_0_0_, custtable0_.memo as memo115_0_0_, custtable0_.modifiedby as modifi116_0_0_, custtable0_.modifieddatetime as modifi117_0_0_, custtable0_.multilinedisc as multil118_0_0_, custtable0_.nit_br as nit_br119_0_0_, custtable0_.numbersequencegroup as number120_0_0_, custtable0_.onetimecustomer as onetim121_0_0_, custtable0_.orderentrydeadlinegroupid as ordere122_0_0_, custtable0_.orgid as orgid123_0_0_, custtable0_.ouraccountnum as ouracc124_0_0_, custtable0_.packagedepositexcempt_pl as packag125_0_0_, custtable0_.packmaterialfeelicensenum as packma126_0_0_, custtable0_.party as party127_0_0_, custtable0_.partycountry as partyc128_0_0_, custtable0_.partystate as partys129_0_0_, custtable0_.passportno_hu as passpo130_0_0_, custtable0_.paymdayid as paymda131_0_0_, custtable0_.paymentreference_ee as paymen132_0_0_, custtable0_.paymidtype as paymid133_0_0_, custtable0_.paymmode as paymmo134_0_0_, custtable0_.paymsched as paymsc135_0_0_, custtable0_.paymspec as paymsp136_0_0_, custtable0_.paymtermid as paymte137_0_0_, custtable0_.pbacustgroupid as pbacus138_0_0_, custtable0_.pdscustrebategroupid as pdscus139_0_0_, custtable0_.pdsfreightaccrued as pdsfre140_0_0_, custtable0_.pdsrebatetmagroup as pdsreb141_0_0_, custtable0_.presencetype_br as presen142_0_0_, custtable0_.pricegroup as priceg143_0_0_, custtable0_.recid as recid144_0_0_, custtable0_.recversion as recver145_0_0_, custtable0_.regnum_w as regnum146_0_0_, custtable0_.residenceforeigncountryregionid_it as reside147_0_0_, custtable0_.rfc_mx as rfc_mx148_0_0_, custtable0_.rfidcasetagging as rfidca149_0_0_, custtable0_.rfiditemtagging as rfidit150_0_0_, custtable0_.rfidpallettagging as rfidpa151_0_0_, custtable0_.salescalendarid as salesc152_0_0_, custtable0_.salesdistrictid as salesd153_0_0_, custtable0_.salesgroup as salesg154_0_0_, custtable0_.salespoolid as salesp155_0_0_, custtable0_.segmentid as segmen156_0_0_, custtable0_.servicecodeondlvaddress_br as servic157_0_0_, custtable0_.shipcarrieraccount as shipca158_0_0_, custtable0_.shipcarrieraccountcode as shipca159_0_0_, custtable0_.shipcarrierblindshipment as shipca160_0_0_, custtable0_.shipcarrierfuelsurcharge as shipca161_0_0_, custtable0_.shipcarrierid as shipca162_0_0_, custtable0_.stateinscription_mx as statei163_0_0_, custtable0_.statisticsgroup as statis164_0_0_, custtable0_.subsegmentid as subseg165_0_0_, custtable0_.suframa_br as sufram166_0_0_, custtable0_.suframanumber_br as sufram167_0_0_, custtable0_.suframapiscofins_br as sufram168_0_0_, custtable0_.suppitemgroupid as suppit169_0_0_, custtable0_.syncentityid as syncen170_0_0_, custtable0_.syncversion as syncve171_0_0_, custtable0_.taxbordernumber_fi as taxbor172_0_0_, custtable0_.taxgroup as taxgro173_0_0_, custtable0_.taxgstreliefgroupheading_my as taxgst174_0_0_, custtable0_.taxlicensenum as taxlic175_0_0_, custtable0_.taxperiodpaymentcode_pl as taxper176_0_0_, custtable0_.taxwithholdcalculate_in as taxwit177_0_0_, custtable0_.taxwithholdcalculate_th as taxwit178_0_0_, custtable0_.taxwithholdgroup_th as taxwit179_0_0_, custtable0_.unitedvatinvoice_lt as united180_0_0_, custtable0_.usecashdisc as usecas181_0_0_, custtable0_.usepurchrequest as usepur182_0_0_, custtable0_.vatnum as vatnum183_0_0_, custtable0_.vendaccount as vendac184_0_0_, custtable0_.websalesorderdisplay as websal185_0_0_ from Custtable custtable0_ where custtable0_.accountnum=? and custtable0_.dataareaid=? and custtable0_.partition=?
2016-09-10 15:28:54.967  WARN 69384 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2016-09-10 15:28:54.967 ERROR 69384 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "custtable" does not exist
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc

Comment: the link you provided, pointed me to the solution:  ALTER USER user_name SET search_path to 'schema'
Will be happy to accept if you post it as an answer. thanks!

Comment: did you find any solution

Answer (score 161):

For Hibernate as JPA provider use

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=dbo`

For plain JDBC, add it to your connection string:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema
```

Another option is to run the statement `set schema 'dbo'` early in each query object. (Yuck!)

BTW your 
`spring.datasource.schema=dbo`
is probably mistake as this property specifies name of the sql file that contains your schema (CREATE/ALTER statements)

Comment: Thanks @anthavio ! it worked for me.

Comment: this is not good since you can only access tables in dbo schema. How about you have another schema?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to change your application.properties's file content like this :

############## DataSource Config #################

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/databaseName?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC+1

spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.hikari.schema=dbo
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.sql.init.encoding= UTF-8
```

############# Hibernate properties #################

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = 
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. The following two lines

```
entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);
additionalProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "dbo");
```

should be in a different order:
first you put default schema in additionalProperties and then set them in entityManagerFactory

```
additionalProperties.put("hibernate.default_schema", "dbo");
entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with my Microservice as well.
When checking the internet, I found a way to do this. 
Source : https://gist.github.com/marisnb/6d08621442a50b33f2104f42f9df9d86


`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema-name`

Comment: Isn't this what the top-voted answer already suggested? If so, then there is no need to add a duplicated answer...

Answer (score 0):

By default, the public schema is used in PostgreSQL.
Any SQL queries executed will run against the public schema by default unless explicitly mentioned.

if your DB have multiple schema you can access by following strategies:

How to access :

1. DB Level -> SET search_path TO schema1,schema2;
2. Table Level -> Specify schema name in @Table annotation (@Table(name = "testtable", schema = "user_service"))
3. Configuration Level -> Specify schema name in properties or yaml file:
   spring:
   jpa:
   properties:
   hibernate:
   dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   default_schema: user_service

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
try (final Connection connection = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).getDataSource().getConnection()) {
    connection.getSchema()
```

}

The best and easiest decision!