# How to know underlying database name via Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am connecting to multiple databases in my spring-boot app using Spring Data JPA by determining which database to connect at runtime. How can I check for validation on which database am I actually connected to on which my queries are running?

Comment: Do you use hibernate multitenancy?

Comment: Yes, I am using multiple datasources and following this tutorial : https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jpa-multi-tenancy-example/

Comment: Which part of this approach do you not trust that you need to validate it?

Comment: On returning the appropriate entity manager, I had a typo and was returning the same entity manager in both cases, hence query running on the same database regardless the input - hence thought arose to validate where I am connecting to. I was able to resolve my actual issue but would still like to explore the possibility of knowing the connection database.

Answer (score 4):

Try to get the URL from the Datasource, maybe will do it:

```
dataSource.getConnection().getMetaData().getURL();
```

Checkout [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) documentation for complete details.

Comment: OP Says he has multiple databases, so he has most likely multiple datasources. To this code the question remains how to get the actually used datasource.

Answer (score 0):

The referred the Answer from:

[how to properly specify database schema in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430422/how-to-properly-specify-database-schema-in-spring-boot)

Just appending the schema name after actual DB host name. For my code MYSQL DB is configured, and this worked fine for me:

```
appname.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://DBhostname.com/schema_test?useSSL=false
```

the key name can be any custom name that suits your application

Answer (score -1):

Only thing i can think of is some like a (simplified)

```
@Entity
public class ConfigDB{
 Integer id;

 String tenant; 
}
```

then have a repository:

```
public ConfigDBRepository extends CrudRepository{
  public boolean existsByTenant(String tenant);
}
```

And the have in every DB this tenant in this table setup for validation.