# Spring Batch "Invalid object name BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE"

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-batch

I've created a spring batch to query a Azure SQL server database and write the data into a CSV file. I do not have `create` permissions for the database. I get this error `Invalid Object name BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE` on running the batch. I don't want the spring batch meta-data tables to be created in the main database. Or it would be helpful if I can have them in another local or in-memory db like h2db.
I've also added `spring-batch-initialize-schema=never` already, which was the case with most answers to similar questions on here, but that didn't help.

**Edit:**

I resolved the `Invalid Object name` error by preventing the metadata tables from being created into the main database by extending the `DefaultBatchConfigurer` Class and Overriding the `setDataSource` method, thus having them created in the in-memory map-repository. Now I want to try two options:

1. How to have the meta data tables to be created in a local db or in-memory db like h2db.
2. Or If I have the meta data tables created already in the main database, in a different schema than my main table I'm fetching from. How to point my job to those meta-data tables in another schema, to store the job and step details data in those.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{

@Override
    public void setDataSource(DataSource datasource) {

    }
...
```

My application.properties file looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

spring-batch-initialize-schema=never
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to have the meta data tables to be created in a local db or in-memory db like h2db.

You can use `spring.batch.initialize-schema=embedded` for that.

> Or If I have the meta data tables created already in the main database, in a different schema than my main table I'm fetching from. How to point my job to those meta-data tables in another schema, to store the job and step details data in those.

spring batch works against a datasource, not a particular schema. If meta-data tables are in a different schema, then you need to create a second datasource pointing to that schema and set it on the job repository.

Comment: I couldn't find any relevant examples or the documentation regarding the same. Can you point me to some, that'd be helpful giving me some direction.

Comment: You can specify the schema in the `spring.datasource.url` property of the datasource in which meta-data tables are created, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430422/how-to-properly-specify-database-schema-in-spring-boot. Please accept this answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a demo with two datasources. Batch metadata will sotre in H2 DB and the Job datasource is Azure SQL.

Here is the project structure:

[image]

1. We need define a `DataSourceConfig` class and use `@Primary` annotation for DataSource bean:

```java
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "mssqlDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource appDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
    @Bean(name = "h2DataSource")
    @Primary
    // @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.h2")
    public DataSource h2DataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url("jdbc:h2:mem:thing:H2;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE")
                .driverClassName("org.h2.Driver")
                .username("sa")
                .password("")                   
                .build();
    }
    
}
```

2. In the ItemReaderDbDemo class, we use  `@Autowired @Qualifier("mssqlDataSource")` to specify the dataSource in the Spring Batch task:

```java
@Configuration
public class ItemReaderDbDemo {
    
    //generate task Object
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    
    //Step exec tasks
    //generate step Object
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mssqlDataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dbJdbcWriter")
    private ItemWriter<? super Todo> dbJdbcWriter;
    
    @Bean
    public Job itemReaderDbDemoJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("itemReaderDbDemoJob").start(itemReaderDbStep()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step itemReaderDbStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("itemReaderDbStep")
                .<Todo,Todo>chunk(2)
                .reader(dbJdbcReader())
                .writer(dbJdbcWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JdbcPagingItemReader<Todo> dbJdbcReader() {
        JdbcPagingItemReader<Todo> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<Todo>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setFetchSize(2);
        reader.setRowMapper(new  RowMapper<Todo>() {
            @Override
            public Todo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Todo todo = new Todo();
                todo.setId(rs.getLong(1));
                todo.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
                todo.setDetails(rs.getString(3));
                return todo;
            }   
            
        });
        SqlServerPagingQueryProvider provider = new  SqlServerPagingQueryProvider();
        provider.setSelectClause("id,description,details");
        provider.setFromClause("from dbo.todo");
        
        //sort
        Map<String,Order> sort = new HashMap<>(1);
        sort.put("id", Order.DESCENDING);
        provider.setSortKeys(sort);
        
        reader.setQueryProvider(provider);
        return reader;
    }
}
```

3. Here is my application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://josephserver2.database.windows.net:1433;database=<Your-Database-Name>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=<Your-UserName>
spring.datasource.password=<Your-Password>
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

4. It return expected result from my Azure SQL. By the way, my Azure sql username does not have create permissions for the database.
   The result shows:
   [image]

Comment: Here is my [code](https://github.com/DDFXulei/spring-batch-hello-world).

Comment: Thanks. It looks well. I am yet to try the implementation myself. Didn't get time the past few days. I'll let you know as soon as I do.

Comment: Hi @Abhinandan Madaan, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Very Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a little bit old, but I'd like to give an update.
For newer versions of Spring Boot spring.batch.initialize-schema is deprecated.
I'm using Spring Boot 2.7.1 and the newer property is **spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema**.
In my case: when I was receiving the error message was due that the user did not have the **CREATE TABLE permission** to create the corresponding spring bacth tables.
Adding the permissions fix the issue.