# SimpleJdbcInsert does not recognize currentschema

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I connect with `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?currentSchema=myschema`.

I have the following configuration for SimpleJdbcInsert. I use Spring Boot.

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("simpleJdbcInsert")
public SimpleJdbcInsert simpleJdbcInsert(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
 return new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("tableX").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
}
```

But i get the following execption:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to locate table meta data for 'tableX' in the default schema
```

I don't know why, because i thought that i set the `currentSchema=myschema` already.

I don't want to do following because i set the `currentSchema=myschema` in the JDBC URL above.

```
new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withSchemaName("Schema1").withTableName("tableX").usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
```

Comment: I guess you could unwrap / cast the datasource to the actual class, then use `getProperty("currentSchema")` to get the parameter. Although it's unclear it's not set in the datasource automatically (maybe it's overridden): https://stackoverflow.com/a/44274949

Comment: Which version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: Version of postgres  is 9.5

Comment: And the version of the postgresql driver?

Comment: I have tested it with 42.0.0 and 42.2.2. But with no success