# Liquibase generateChangeLog doesn't retrieve all schemas with postgres

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I m new to liquibase and tried to generate a changelog from an existing database
my database contains 3 schemas when I execute the following command :

```
    Liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
              --classpath=postgresqljdbc4.jar 
              --changeLogFile=db.changelog.xml 
              --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_bd" 
              --username=username 
              --password=password 
              generateChangeLog
```

the db.changelog.xml is generated but it retrieve only one schemas information

> How to get all the schemas information

note that every schema contains tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquibase only works with a single schema at a time, so you would need to tell it which schema to generate a changelog for, and do that three times. You can specify the schema for postgres in the url. See this question for details:

[Is it possible to specify the schema when connecting to postgres with JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc)

If you need to work with multiple schemas, you might want to look at Datical DB, as that product has the ability to work with multiple schemas in a single changelog.

(disclaimer: I work for Datical)

Comment: So the best way is to create a master changelog and include in it the changeLog of every schemas??

Comment: That could be one possible approach. Datical has actually extended Liquibase quite a bit and can handle multiple schemas in a single changelog without using includes, so that is not the approach that we use.