# i found some issues to run the application

Tags: spring-boot

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

```
Property: driverclassname
Value: org.postgresql.Driver
Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
Reason: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
```

Action:

Update your application's configuration

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Exception when creating datasource with PostgreSQL driver in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53741514/exception-when-creating-datasource-with-postgresql-driver-in-spring-boot).
The error also occurs for incompatible driver versions. Please verify the same.
Please let me know if you need more details

Comment: class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist  
// look what i got .

Comment: any social media account to more connexion ?