# Hikari CP Java springboot getConnection error after some days of deployment

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I'm connecting to my postgres instance in springboot and I've implemented Hikari CP for connection pooling . I see after a few days of deployment , my code seems to break I seem to get the following error message in my logs

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 60000ms.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:602)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:195)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:145)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:85)
atcom.dell.it.daas.apibuilder.submitrequestservice.Services.PostgresConnectionServiceImpl.connectToPostgresDatabase(PostgresConnectionServiceImpl.java:103)
at com.dell.it.daas.apibuilder.submitrequestservice.Services.PostgresConnectionServiceImpl.getRequestDetailsByRequestId(PostgresConnectionServiceImpl.java:114)
```

Here's my Hikari CP connection parameters

```
public static Connection connectToPostgresDatabase(String connectionString, String userName, String 
password)
        throws SQLException {

    if (config == null) {
        config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl(connectionString);
        config.setUsername(userName);
        config.setPassword(password);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "256");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
        config.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
        config.setMinimumIdle(10);
        config.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
        config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(60000);
        config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
        config.setInitializationFailTimeout(20000);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("prepareThreshold", 0);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("useServerPrepStmts", true);


        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
    }


    return ds.getConnection();

}
```

SO whenever I need to execute any Query I get the connection to database as

```
 try(Connection con = 
PostgresConnectionServiceImpl.connectToPostgresDatabase(apibuilderConnectionString, 
apibuilderUserName, apibuilderPassword))
    {
        if(getSchema()!=null)
            con.setSchema(getSchema());


            try(PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(queryToRetrieveRequestDetails);
                ResultSet requestDetailsSet = st.executeQuery();)
```

I'm using try with resources to do all my database related operations

```
PostgresConnectionServiceImpl.connectToPostgresDatabase(apibuilderConnectionString, 
apibuilderUserName, apibuilderPassword)
```

This is the the line which is failing .

Been struggling with this for some time now appreciate any help . Thanks

Comment: Did you get leak warnings in log? Did your server(s) had load in that time? can you show connectToPostgresDatabase? also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213381/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-for-postgresql

Comment: I've already pasted connectToPostgresDatabase function which does all the hikari CP configurations

Comment: Why this solution? You are bypassing the Spring connection management here? That being said make sure you configure your pool correctly so that it does idle checking and validation of the connection while nothing is being used so that you always have fresh connections. You shouldn't be using a test query as JDBC4+ has better means of testing/validating a connection.

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm using Hikari for Connection pooling instead of spring's default connection pooling . Can you guide me to some materials that I can take reference ?

Comment: Hikari IS the default connection pool used by Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you tell me what is wrong with my configurations and how I can modify them to solve this issue ?