# HikariCP: Why does connection leak and unleak result in "connection attempt timed out" for new DB connection?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp

I am running a Spring boot Java application using default HikariCP as data source:

- Hikari version - 3.4.5
- Spring Boot version - 2.4.5 running in AWS EKS
- JDBI version - 3.9.1
- DB - AWS RDS Postgres

My Spring application becomes unresponsive as it loses all the connections in the Hikari Pool. This does not happen deterministically, but once it starts happening, the only recovery possible is through restart.

Hikari Config:
[image: hikari-config]

The pool keeps losing the connections and fails to connect back, leaving `total=0` connections.

```
06-23 08:14:33.242 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
06-23 08:15:07.189 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)
06-23 08:15:07.190 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
06-23 08:15:32.785 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@58f866df: (connection was evicted)
06-23 08:15:41.278 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=9, active=1, idle=8, waiting=0)
06-23 08:15:49.809 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Failed to create/setup connection: Connection attempt timed out.
06-23 08:15:49.809 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Cannot acquire connection from data source
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection attempt timed out.
        at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.getResult(Driver.java:422)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:725)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:711)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
06-23 08:15:49.810 [HikariPool-1 connection adder] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Connection add failed, sleeping with backoff: 250ms
06-23 08:15:49.816 [HikariPool-1 connection closer] DEBUG PoolBase - HikariPool-1 - Closing connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@7303422e: (connection was evicted)

(After more of these)
06-23 10:23:21.731 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Add connection elided, waiting 2, queue 10
06-23 10:23:55.883 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-7] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
06-23 10:23:55.883 [pool-3-thread-4] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Timeout failure stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
06-23 10:23:55.883 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)
06-23 10:23:55.883 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] DEBUG HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.
```

FWIW, I've found the logs for leak detection, but they are followed by `unleaked` logs. The leak threshold is set to 20 seconds.

```
06-23 08:07:04.506 [HikariPool-1 housekeeper] WARN  ProxyLeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered for org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@58f866df on thread ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:223)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.getAutoCommit(Unknown Source)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.transaction.LocalTransactionHandler.isInTransaction(LocalTransactionHandler.java:118)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.Handle.(Handle.java:76)
        at org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi.open(Jdbi.java:309)
        (Application specific stacktrace)
...

06-23 08:07:04.527 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  ProxyLeakTask - Previously reported leaked connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@58f866df on thread ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1 was returned to the pool (unleaked)
```

When I redeploy the application, it starts up perfectly, and other instances of this application work correctly, so I have ruled out issues on network and RDS side.

My questions:

1. Is connection leaks the source of problem? As they are `unleaked`, shouldn't Hikari be able to reclaim the connections and create new ones? Is there a way to confirm the root cause?
2. The leaks don't happen often, but when they do, they start happening for several requests until the app becomes unresponsive. Is there a way to find out why the requests start taking more than 20 seconds?
3. What config changes can help with more diagnosis and further, to fix the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't close connection, hikari can't know you need/want to close it

You must find where you aren't closing connection properly in code

You can reduce the leaks by setting a lower [maxLifetime](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) to return the connection to pool sooner

> This property controls the maximum lifetime of a connection in the pool. An in-use connection will never be retired, only when it is closed will it then be removed. On a connection-by-connection basis, minor negative attenuation is applied to avoid mass-extinction in the pool. We strongly recommend setting this value, and it should be several seconds shorter than any database or infrastructure imposed connection time limit. A value of 0 indicates no maximum lifetime (infinite lifetime), subject of course to the idleTimeout setting. The minimum allowed value is 30000ms (30 seconds). Default: 1800000 (30 minutes)

Follow Hikari's configuration tips for [PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213381/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-for-postgresql)
You can add monitor tools/code, but you must fix the problem