# Why does HikariCP say "Property database does not exist on target class org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, hikaricp

I am attempting to set up various PostgreSQL JDBC driver [properties](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) to my HikariCP pool, but for some reason, it's stating that those properties don't exist. Why so? Am I using the wrong parameter names?

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class HikariTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName("org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource");
        config.setUsername("[REDACTED]");
        config.setPassword("[REDACTED]");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("host", "[REDACTED");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("database", "[REDACTED]");
        config.addDataSourceProperty("ssl", true);
        config.addDataSourceProperty("sslcert", "[REDACTED]");
        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Property database does not exist on target class org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setProperty(PropertyElf.java:127)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.lambda$setTargetFromProperties$0(PropertyElf.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1603)
    at java.base/java.util.Properties.forEach(Properties.java:1422)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.PropertyElf.setTargetFromProperties(PropertyElf.java:46)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:323)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.<init>(PoolBase.java:112)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:93)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81)
    at HikariTest.main(HikariTest.java:21)
```

Comment: I believe it should be `"databaseName", "[REDACTED]"` not `"database", "[REDACTED]"`.

Comment: See also the examples here: [How do I configure HikariCP for postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213381/how-do-i-configure-hikaricp-for-postgresql)

Comment: Hello @andrewJames, is there a comprehensive list of property names somewhere? Sorry if this sounds idiotic.

Comment: See the HikariCP web site for all the HikariCP settings. And see the relevant Postgres JDBC documentation for all the Postgres JDBC settings.

Comment: I've seen both sites, and sometimes the names don't correspond as in the case above - the Postgres JDBC driver says "database" is the name of the database name parameter.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to configure an object of type `PGSimpleDataSource` first. After that is done, pass to [`HikariConfig#setDataSource`](https://javadoc.io/static/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/5.0.1/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig.html#setDataSource(javax.sql.DataSource)).

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for the suggestion. Didn't realize that was an option, and seems less ambiguous than the direct approach of adding properties using `addDataSourceProperty("something", "the_other_thing")`.  I'll use that in the future.

Comment: @daferrecpr If my suggested approach works out, please come back here to draft, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question, for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gives that error because [`PGSimpleDataSource`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGSimpleDataSource.html) does not have a property `database` (i.e. it doesn't have a `setDatabase(String)` method). It does have a property `databaseName` ([`setDatabaseName`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.html#setDatabaseName-java.lang.String-) defined in [`BaseDataSource`](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/common/BaseDataSource.html)). This property is specified in section *9.6.1 `DataSource` Properties* of the JDBC 4.3 specification.

Reading the comments, it looks like you're confusing the documentation of the [JDBC URL format](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) (and connection properties) with the properties that are available on the data source implementations provided by the driver. To be clear, that documentation doesn't specify there is a property `database`, it only uses `database` as a placeholder in the JDBC URL syntax (as in jdbc:postgresql://*host*/***database***).