# Setting schema in PostgreSQL JDBC doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, schema

I created schema "customer1" with table "user" and I'm trying to connect it from JDBC using Connection.setSchema():

```
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/project";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", "postgres");
props.setProperty("password", "postgres");

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props)) {
    conn.setSchema("customer1");

    try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SHOW search_path")) {
        rs.next();
        System.out.println("search_path: " + rs.getString(1));
    }

    try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM user LIMIT 1")) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("user name: " + rs.getString("name"));
        }
    }
}
```

This code prints:

```
search_path: customer1
```

and then it throws PSQLException with message:

```
ERROR: column "name" does not exist
```

If I qualify "user" table in SELECT query:

```
try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM customer1.user LIMIT 1")) {
    if (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println("user name: " + rs.getString("name"));
    }
}
```

then it prints:

```
search_path: customer1
user name: name1
```

and no error occur. I'm using JDBC driver 42.2.2 and PostgreSQL server 10.4. Why setting schema doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user` is a [built-in function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) (and a keyword). So you can't really use it as a table name:

```
psql (10.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# select user;
   user
----------
 postgres
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from user;
   user
----------
 postgres
(1 row)
```

And because it's a function it does not have a column `name`.

```
postgres=# select name from user;
ERROR:  column "name" does not exist
LINE 1: select name from user;
               ^
postgres=#
```

If you qualify the table, then it's clear that you are not referencing the function, but the table.

You can either always qualify the table name with the schema, or use [double quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS): `select name from "user";` or simply find a table name that does not collide with built-in functions.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77816297/16827925

Updated on 2024

If you want to set schema, use `?options=-c%20search_path=`

Full url

```sql
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?options=-c%20search_path=test,public,pg_catalog
```

According to the postgresql JDBC doc https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/