# I can connect to AWS RDS via sqldeveloper but can't by Java application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, oracle-sqldeveloper, amazon-rds

It is so werid that I can connect to AWS RDS with sqldeveloper but can't with my java application(java source code or jsp)

When I try to access to RDS, there are errors like:

```
coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Jun-2018 04:24:33.203 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Jun-2018 04:24:33.212 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Jun-2018 04:24:33.215 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
26-Jun-2018 04:24:33.219 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1387 ms
26-Jun-2018 04:24:33.265 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
26-Jun-2018 04:24:33.266 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.50
26-Jun-2018 04:24:33.286 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
26-Jun-2018 04:24:35.020 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
26-Jun-2018 04:24:35.097 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT has finished in 1,811 ms
26-Jun-2018 04:24:35.100 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
26-Jun-2018 04:24:35.106 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
26-Jun-2018 04:24:35.108 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1888 ms
Loading driver...
Driver loaded!
jdbc:oracle:thin://IP:1521/ORCL?user=username&password=password
SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
SQLState: 99999
VendorError: 17067
Closing the connection.
SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified
SQLState: 99999
VendorError: 17067
Closing the connection.
```

But the URL is just the same value as I tried with sqldeveloper.

Is there anything wrong?

Please enlighten me since I've been suffering for this about a week! :(

Comment: Does it fail immediately, or does it take a while before it fails?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein It fails immediatly. Because right after I try, I go check logo. And the message is already there.

Comment: username and password go into the properties not the url

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your application is set up, but I'm using Maven & Spring Boot and I got it working like this:

I mainly followed this guide, ignoring the .sql files, thymeleaf UI, "model.addAttribute("cities", cities);" part, and the html file:
https://zetcode.com/springboot/postgresql/

My application.properties file looks like this

```
postgres.comment.aa=https://zetcode.com/springboot/postgresql/
spring.main.banner-mode=off
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://your-rds-url-here.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:yourDbPortHere/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=<your db password here>

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

If you have custom schemas, you can append "?currentSchema=users" to the url:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://your-rds-url-here.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:yourDbPortHere/postgres?currentSchema=users
```

Thanks to this SO answer for the schema:
[Is it possible to specify the schema when connecting to postgres with JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc)

These other couple links also helped
https://turreta.com/2015/03/01/how-to-specify-a-default-schema-when-connecting-to-postgresql-using-jdbc/

https://doc.cuba-platform.com/manual-latest/db_schema_connection.html