# Nifi - Unable to find schema in LookupRecord

Tags: apache-nifi

In Apache NiFi, unable to configure databse schema. I'm trying to find a record in PostgesSQL using `LookupRecord`. But unable to specify the schema name as there is no such option. It's looking by default in public schema. Please help me with this.

Comment: Any updates on this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the particular schema as part of the JDBC URL in newer versions of the Postgres driver. [See example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820666/284538).