# AWS Athena/AWS Lambda unable to specify the schema for Federated Query

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I am using Athena Federated Query, with a connection to Amazon RDS. When setting up the connection, in the section for the lambda function for JdbcConnectorConfig, DefaultConnectionString I use:

```
postgres://jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres?user=myUser&password=myPassword
```

This works well, However I notice in Athena that when I use this connection I get 2 databases:

- pg_catalog: is empty
- public: where the desire tables are

[image: Athena Databases multiple options]

Do i need to amend this connection string and how? in order to have only the tables within public been display. I have review the following documentation:
[PostgreSQL JDBC Driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html)

I tried unsuccessfully, and following similar question in stackoverflow ([Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc))

```
postgres://jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres?user=myUser&password=myPassword&currentSchema=public
```

and also

```
postgres://jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres?user=myUser&password=myPassword&searchpath=public
```

and also

```
postgres://jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx.xxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres?user=myUser&password=myPassword&options=--search_path=public
```

Comment: Is everything working okay, but you just don't want `pg_catalog` appearing as a Database? Is that causing a particular problem for you if it is displayed?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein initially I thought it was causing an error in my AWS Quicksights connection, but now I realised its not, so I guess at this stage is more a learn thing :)

Comment: BTW, it is showing a list of **databases**, not **schemas**.

Comment: maby need to recrawl spill / output bucket?