# Slick 3 - how to get correct (database) schema when inserting with plain SQL

Tags: postgresql, scala, akka, slick, akka-projection

I'm trying to get basic plain SQL example working in Slick 3, on Postgres but with custom DB schema, say `local` instead of default `public` one. I have hard time inserting the row as executing the following

```
sqlu"INSERT INTO schedule(user_id, product_code, run_at)  VALUES ($userId, $code, $nextRun)"
```

says

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "schedule" does not exist
```

The table is in place because when I prefix `schedule` with `local.` in the insert statement it works as expected. How can I get correct schema provided to this query?

I'm using it as part of akka-projection handler and all the projection internals like maintaining offsets work as expected on `local` schema.

I cannot simply put `schema` as a variable as it errors while resolving parameters:

```
sqlu"INSERT INTO ${schema}.schedule(user_id, product_code, run_at)  VALUES ($userId, $code, $nextRun)"
```

Comment: How about at JDBC connection level? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168689/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-schema-when-connecting-to-postgres-with-jdbc#4820666

Comment: Crap, too many configs. Didn't have schema specified at this exact one. So not really that, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You can insert schema name using `#${value}`:

```
sqlu"INSERT INTO #${schema}.table ..."
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that syntax. But the issue was I had some mess in my config and schema wasn't properly configured.